# How can I figure out the singularity problem in estimating the indicator variable coefficient in time series model ?

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive, quantile-regression, singular-matrix

I want to capture the role of the sign of the previous return in my time series model(AR(1) and QAR(1)) in R both with quantile and OLS regression , but I face error. Here is the code:

```
stockreturns22=data.frame(ret22=(data22)[,4],
                          timestamps=(data22)[,2],format="%Y/%m/%d")
stockreturns22.ts= xts(stockreturns22$ret22, 
order.by=as.Date(stockreturns22$timestamps))
rt22=ts(stockreturns22$ret22)
tt22=length(rt22)
lm22=lm(rt22[-1]~rt22[-tt22]+rt22[-tt22]:I(rt22[-tt22]<0))
summary(lm22)

tauseq=c(0.02,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.9,0.98)
qslope22=NULL; qr22=list()
qqslope22=NULL; 
for(i in 1:length(tauseq)){

qr22[[i]]=rq(rt22[-1]~rt22[-tt22]+rt22[-tt22]:I(rt22[-tt22]
<0),tau=tauseq[i])
forecast(qr22)
qslope22[i]=qr22[[i]]$coef[2]
qqslope22[i]=qr22[[i]]$coef[3]
}
```

Here is the answer for the OLS. It can not compute the third coefficient which is for the previous return:

```
Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    

(Intercept)                         504.65017   14.84839   33.99   <2e-16 
***
rt22[-tt22]                           0.34867    0.01603   21.75   <2e-16 
***    
rt22[-tt22]:I(rt22[-tt22] <= 0)TRUE        NA         NA      NA       NA    

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and the answer for Quantile AutoRegression is :

```
Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks for your time and consideration